# Getting Negative Values Using clock_gettime

Tags: c, time, clock

In the following program, I have tried to measure the execution time of a job(for loop). Most of the time it works fine, however, sometimes, it returns negative values!! My first guess is that the variable may get overflowed. Can anyone please let me whether I am right or not? How can I solve the problem?

Thanks

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
long int ST;
long int ET;
struct timespec gettime_now;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &gettime_now);
ST= gettime_now.tv_nsec;
for (i=0; i < 1000; i++)
  a[i]=b[i];
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &gettime_now);
ET= gettime_now.tv_nsec;
printf("Time diff: %ld\n", ET-ST);
}
```

Comment: Please see: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659867/how-can-i-check-how-many-times-a-function-was-called-with-a-3-seconds-interval/

For how to time a function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are neglecting `tv_sec` of `struct timespec` in both the cases and just using nano-second which is not correct as `ST` and `EV`'s tv_nsec may be of different second's.

From [man](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime),

`tv_sec` - represents seconds since epoch

`tv_nsec` - **current second** in nano-second precision *(1/1000000000 sec)*

It is better to write own function to find the difference. Sample code (not tested),

```
timespec diff(timespec start, timespec end)
{
    timespec temp;

    if ((end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec)<0
    {
            temp.tv_sec = end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec-1;
            temp.tv_nsec = 1000000000+end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec;
    }
    else 
    {
            temp.tv_sec = end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec;
            temp.tv_nsec = end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Refer [this](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2007/09/22/profiling-code-using-clock_gettime/) for actual `diff` function and example.

Comment: I am sure that the job I am measuring takes less than 1 sec. So, I ignored the tv_sec part.

Comment: Yes, you are right.... Just understood. I'll give it a shot and then will report the result here.